# How to define per-layer learning rate in mxnet.gluon?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, mxnet

I know that it is possible to freeze  layers in a network for example to train only the last layers of a pre-trained model. 
However, I want to know is there any way to apply certain learning rates to different layers. For example, in pytorch it would be:

```
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([
                    {'params': paras['conv1'], 'lr': learning_rate / 10},
                    {'params': paras['middle'], 'lr': learning_rate / 3},
                    {'params': paras['fc'], 'lr': learning_rate }
                 ], lr=learning_rate)
```

Interfaces of gluon and torch are pretty much the same. Any idea how I can do this in gluon?

Answer (score 3):

You can adjust the learning rate in each layer by modifying `lr_mult`:

```
for key, value in model.collect_params().items():
   print value.lr_mult
```